# Weird QT serial port read and write issue

Tags: serial-port, qt6

I have serial client-server application using QT 6 which is using RS485 (half-duplex serial protocol) .
I am having server application from Windows and Client from Linux.
I am facing the issue is that If no server is running client is reading its own write .

ByteArray data = serial.readAll();

when no server keeps on printing

> Something start Hello from Application Client %1\n.

I've made sure that the software configuration ensures that there's no "echo" causing the message to be read back.

Despite taking these steps, the problem persists. Every time I send a message from the Linux box, I read the same message back.
I've tried adding delays and making other adjustments to the code, but the issue remains. Tried also with different ports , seems the issue persists. Now I need to figure out what's causing this unexpected behavior .Any suggestion.

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <QSerialPort>
#include <QTextStream>
#include <QTimer>

// THIS IS THE CLIENT (Application Client, SLAVE)

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);

    QSerialPort serial;
    serial.setPortName("/dev/ttyS5");
    serial.setBaudRate(QSerialPort::Baud115200);
    serial.setDataBits(QSerialPort::Data8);
    serial.setParity(QSerialPort::OddParity);
    serial.setStopBits(QSerialPort::OneStop);
    serial.setFlowControl(QSerialPort::NoFlowControl);

    if (!serial.open(QIODevice::ReadWrite)) {
        qWarning() << "Failed to open port";
        return -1;
    }

    // Clearing the buffers to avoid residual data
    serial.clear();

    // Listen to messages from server (Server)
    QObject::connect(&serial, &QSerialPort::readyRead, [&serial] {
        QByteArray data = serial.readAll();
        QString expectedMessage = "Hello from Server"; // Correcting the expected message
        if (data.startsWith(expectedMessage.toUtf8())) {
            QTextStream(stdout) << "Correct data received: " << data;

            // when server has finished sending we can send data back
            static int count = 0;
            QString message = QString("Hello from Application Client %1\n").arg(count++);
            serial.write(message.toUtf8());
        } else {
            QTextStream(stdout) << "Incorrect data received: " << data;
        }
    });
    QTimer::singleShot(1000, [&serial] {
       QString message = QString("Something start Hello from Application Client %1\n");
       serial.write(message.toUtf8());
   });
    return a.exec();
}
```